# Akka test case assertion failure

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I am trying to write test for an actor which sends:

```
sender() ! Status.Failure(message)
```

I have written the test case as:

```
class TestActorSpec
    extends TestKit(ActorSystem("system"))
    with ImplicitSender
    with WordSpecLike
    with Matchers {
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher
  implicit val futureDuration: FiniteDuration             = 60.seconds
  val timeout: FiniteDuration                             = 5.seconds
  val testActorRef: ActorRef                              = system.actorOf(Props(new TestActor()), "test-actor")

  val futureResult: Future[Any] = (testActorRef ? "Exception")(timeout)

  "TestSpec" should {
    "send the exception in {
      expectMsgType[Status.Failure]
    }
  }
}
```

But i am getting the test failure with reason:

**[info]   java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsgClass waiting for class akka.actor.Status$Failure
[info]   at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:223)**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to receive `Status.Failure` as a message, you should not use ask pattern `?` and use tell `!` instead.

The reason is that ask pattern will consume the `Failure` and pass back a failed `Future`. In case of ask pattern, you need to assert a failed `Future`.

From Scala docs of `akka.actor.Status.Failure`

> This class/message type is preferably used to indicate failure of some operation performed.
>   As an example, it is used to signal failure with AskSupport is used (ask/?).